# How to count an average for duplicates based on two other columns

Tags: sql

I have the following structure of data:

```
average | date          | hash
20      | 2017-08-29    | 9xxx
15      | 2017-08-29    | 9xxx
26      | 2017-08-29    | 1as0
24      | 2017-09-01    | 1as0
21      | 2017-09-01    | 1as0
22      | 2017-12-20    | 9xxx
21      | 2017-12-20    | 1as0
24      | 2017-12-20    | 1as0
...     | ...           | ...
```

Columns date & hash have duplicates.

I'm trying to build a SQL query that will help me to get rid of duplicates (hash & date). However, I need to accumulate all the values from average from duplicates for the final average per date and per hash.

**In other words, I'd like to receive:**

1. Average for hash based on all duplicated values (from hash column)
2. Per date

So it should look like:

```
average | date          | hash
17. 5   | 201-08-29     | 9xxx
26      | 2017-08-29    | 1as0
22.5    | 2017-09-01    | 1as0
22      | 2017-12-20    | 9xxx
22.5    | 2017-12-20    | 1as0
...     | ...           | ...
```

It looks rather simple, but I'm new to SQL, so it might be not so obvious to me. I spend many hours googling and I didn't find a solution that I was able to implement with a success.

For now, I tried some queries with DISTINCT, GROUP BY and inner query. Each time I miss something (like an average of some subgroups per date for instance).

**My last idea was to:**

1. To create a separate column with the average for each hash and then...
2. ... to group values per date

But in such a solution, the average is done for all hashes not per hash subgroups (duplicates).
I'm not able to grasp all values per each date (year/month/day).

```
SELECT *, AVG(avg_tmpr_c) OVER (PARTITION BY wthr_date) as av_for_hash
FROM testing
```

Anyone will be so kind to help me?

Comment: Please include your expected results for the supplied sample data.

Comment: I suspect that two of your calculated averages have typos.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select "date", hash, avg(average) as avg
from tbl
group by "date", hash
```

Comment: Thanks! What a shame, it's so simple and so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

First we collect the total of average per hash and date.
This could be saved in a temporary table.
Then we add them and we compute the last average.

`select date, hash , sum(average ) sum_a , count(*) count_a  from tbl  group by date, hash`

--- per date

```
select date , sum(sum_a) / sum(count_a) as date_avg from 
( select date, hash , sum(average ) sum_a , count(*) count_a 
from tbl 
group by date, hash ) a
group by date
```

--- per hash

```
select hash , sum(sum_a) / sum(count_a) as hash_avg from 
( select date, hash , sum(average ) sum_a , count(*) count_a 
from tbl 
group by date, hash ) a
group by hash
```